# Is it safe to unplug, without first unmounting, a USB drive that was mounted as read only?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, mount, ubuntu-12.04

I'm using Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 and usbmount for auto-mounting USB pen drives as read-only.

Also, in this particular scenario, is it possible (and proper) to automatically perform the unmount action after the unplug event is detected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1121449#p1121449) post on the Archlinux forums, it is safe to do that for drives that are mounted read-only.

> Technically in terms of read-only you can unplug an USB drive.